# Decode Base64 text with Cyrillic+Latin letters to JSON

Tags: node.js, json, base64

I couldn't find how to convert Base64 string which contains Cyrillic and Latin letters to JSON.
I have tried using Buffer, but it does not show Cyrillic letters after conversion.

What I have tried: `const convert_to_string = Buffer.from(report64, 'base64').toString("ascii")`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using utf8 like this `const convert_to_string = Buffer.from(report64, 'base64').toString("utf8 ")`